# MySQLDump to local machine from remote server connected via SSH

Tags: ssh, mysql

```
mysqldump -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -u username -ppassword databasename > C:\path\to\store\file
```

It seemed to work as it paused while the file was downloading, however no file appears once it completes.

Do I have something wrong in the command line?

Comment: Are you sure that you have permissions to write to that location?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Use like this:

```
mysqldump -P3306  -h192.168.20.151 -u root -p database > c:/my.sql
```

Hope to help you:)

---

Edition for linux

```
mysqldump -u root -p databasename > ~/Downlaods/filename.sql
```

Comment: should i run it from terminal ?

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me as you need both a mysql login and a server login via ssh I'm assuming

Comment: This works because it's connecting to the MySQL server, not SSH. So as long as the server is bound to an IP you can access, this will work. If you're running MySQL and HTTP on the same machine and have MySQL bound only to localhost you will need to SSH into the server to run this command and SCP the result file. In most setups you more than likely can do this remotely or at the very least with a VPN connection.

Comment: Yeah, this answer is assuming that someone have mysql port open. Not default on for example aws.

Comment: Is there a more secure solution that I can just copy and use ? In a case where i don't want to expose mysql to internet, How can i backup files to my local desktop from a server running mysql ?

Answer (score 2):

Simply run `mysqldump -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -u username -ppassword databasename > C:\path\to\store\file` from the command prompt on your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you involve ssh in your question but...

First try the same command without redirecting it to a file to see that you can connect to the database.

Second make sure that you can write to that location (try to create and edit a file in the same path).

If those to work your command should work.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using SSH to connect to a remote server. When I run this command it creates a file in the directory where I run the command from and names it C:\path which is more than likely my .sql file I need, is there a way that I can get it to download from a remote server locally to my home computer?

Comment: You can either execute mysqldump locally on your machine or you can log in to the server with ssh, run mysqldump there, and then scp the file to your computer after it has finished.